# When calling dealloc from a UIView with ARC, can I assume ivars are still retained?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, key-value-observing

I am adding a KVO observer on a subclass of UIView to one of its subviews. I also have a strong reference to the subview. When I call `removeObserver` on the subview in `dealloc`, can I assume that the subview still exists? I don't want to leak the observer.

Basically, when `dealloc` is called in ARC, is the automatic call to `[super dealloc]` before or after this call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

> A class may provide a method definition for an instance method named
>   `dealloc`. This method will be called after the final `release` of the
>   object but before it is deallocated or any of its instance variables
>   are destroyed. The superclass’s implementation of `dealloc` will be
>   called automatically when the method returns.

So `[super dealloc]` is called *after* calling the subclass `dealloc` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The automatic call to [super dealloc] is "after".

Your strong ivars are still valid in dealloc.